# Windows Forms Designer Code modifies user control collections and objects

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, custom-controls, designer

VS 2010, Windows 7: Windows Forms - I have a number of forms that contain user controls that reference domain model objects. Some of the controls reference single objects and some reference collections of domain model objects. When I open the project or individual forms, the IDE will check out the forms and add dummy domain model objects. In some cases, this has no serious side effects and in others this result in the app crashing. Why is this happening and how do I prevent this from happening in the future? I would like to get to the point where the designer doesn't add anything extraneous - I can crash the system on my thank you very much. Thanks.

Comment: Use the DesignMode property to prevent code running at design time.

Answer (score 0):

The designer will create a default instance for each public property contained in child user-controls in the current control it is displaying. This can be changed using the [`DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.visibility.aspx) setting the visibility to `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden`.

This tells the designer to leave those properties alone.

You will likely have to go through the designer file itself and remove the old allocations and assignments for the properties you marked.